# Enterprise Architect - state machine export image - borders

Tags: export, border, enterprise-architect, state-machine

I have a small problem with EA13:

Whenever I export any diagram to any image format, it will print a border around it (which I want). You can find these settings in:

```
Start -> Workspace -> Preferences -> Diagram -> Diagram Frames
```

The strange thing (/bug?) is, that there is no such frame/border for a state machine diagram.
It will appear when I drag and drop the state machine to another diagram, but not when I export the image.

---

**TL;DR:**

I want the border of the right image to be exported automatically, but I only get the left image.
[image: State machine borders]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

EA is consequently inconsequent...

You need to create a `State Machine` from the toolbox:

[image]

This creates a diagram inside which contains a frame (named as the state machine). This will (of course) export with a frame - namely the one you see above.

Comment: This is one big step forward! The thing is: I only want the frame to be visible when the image is exported. I've tested your solution and this will create a frame inside of the diagram. I want to see the left side of the image in EA and the right one only after export. Just like with any other diagram (except state machines ...).

Comment: You might go ahead and report that as bug. But as I know those guys they tell you it's a feature :-/